# How do I stop patches from showing through paint?

Tags: painting

I've painted a patched, bare plaster wall with a medium purple claypaint (Earthborn, "Jack Horner" color). The few places where I've patched the wall the paint is significantly darker, even after a mist coat, a full coat, and two further goes at spot painting those areas. It seems to be an absorption issue, as each time the patched areas took far, far longer to dry than the areas around them. How can I remedy this?

Below is a photo I took a bit after spot painting one of the patched areas with a roller. The new paint directly on the patched cracks is still quite wet, while the paint to each side is nearer to being dry.

[image: wall]

Comment: Did you use primer?

Comment: I used the paint thinned 4:1 as a mist coat first. The manufacturer recommended that for bare plaster walls.

Comment: How long did you let the patching material dry?

Comment: I did the patches a week before the mist coat.

Comment: They have interesting products. Probably not available in NA.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson Earthborn's claypaint has always been pleasant to paint with---usually covers well and has high opacity, hides a lot of small imperfections, doesn't smell chemical. I'd never seen them before I was in the UK.

Comment: Since it's a water based paint it WILL soak into plaster really well, and will only form a thin skin on top of what was probably acrylic paint before.
You probably should have primed it with a paint that was similar to the existing paint first. As for correction at this point....

Comment: I pained over no acrylic paint here, just bare plaster and my patch. There was no existing paint.

Comment: Yr gonna have to re-skim the patches, then prime w/ some good blocking primer, and then repaint.  Clearly the patch material is more porous than the existing plaster.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Doesn't the fact that the paint took far longer to dry on the patch than on the surrounding plaster suggest that the patch material is _less_ porous than the plaster? Am I crazy to think that?

Comment: @uckelman maybe.  I was thinking the patch acted like a sponge, releasing paint (which could not dry while in the spongy part) slowly to the front surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this the hard way, by sanding off the impermeable filler. I was kind of a pain, but did get me the desired result:

[image: fixed wall]

For reference, the filler was Everbuild Deep Gap Filler. It's worked well for me elsewhere, but seems quite incompatible with clay paints, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dedicated primer.  It might be best to do 2 coats around the patched areas.  Another coat of the purple paint *might* do the trick on its own, but why risk it?  A coat or two of primer will cover a multitude of cracks and patchwork.  They even sell stuff now that is pink when wet and white when dry so you can tell where you've primed.